# In CQL describe keyword is not workng

Tags: cassandra, datastax

Describe command is not working in Datastax DevCentre.
It is showing describe is not a valid key.

My version is DevCenter 1.6.0

Please help on this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Few commands like **DESCRIBE** are restricted to cqlsh and not yet available for DevCenter.

You can find list of these commands here.
http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/cqlshCommandsTOC.html

Comment: is there any solution to check this. I'm trying to connect to my remote machine it is not connecting, command is cqlsh [ip-address].

Answer (score 3):

Describe can be used in cqlsh or apache zeppelin. In dev center, you can browse information about your keyspaces can be inspected and manipulated through the schema view.